# Changing Reconciling-Check-Interval in TFS Build Notification Tool

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Is it possible to change the default check interval of the TFS Build Notification Tool from 2 minutes to a smaller value? It's getting on my nerves an I hope MS has decided to give it an interval parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the polling interval for the Build Notification tool is obtained from a registry setting; I've set it to 10 seconds in the example below:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\Build\BuildNotification\Subscriptions]
"PollingInterval"="00:00:10"
```

Comment: I will check this at this evening. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Id did the job! Now I don't have to wait that long. Cool. Should be added to the TFS books IMO.